# Pandas list condition and values assignment

Tags: pandas, list, conditional-statements

```
conditions3 = [
      ( 
     (df['RSHL_WD']<2)&(df['RSHL_WD']>=0),
     (df['RSHL_WD']<4)&(df['RSHL_WD']>=2),
     (df['RSHL_WD']<6)&(df['RSHL_WD']>=4),
     (df['RSHL_WD']<8)&(df['RSHL_WD']>=6),
     (df['RSHL_WD']>=8),
      )
]
```

## create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition

values3 = ['0','2','4','6','8']

## create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments

df['RSHL_WD1']=np.select(conditions3,values3)

df.head()

I am getting an error "list of cases must be same length as list of conditions"

Could anyone suggest a way to avoid this error

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis in your conditions list. Remove it.

Comment: You can also do it with [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)